# Zend Server Failed During Initialization

Tags: ubuntu, zend-framework, zend-server

I am trying to install `Zend Server` in `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. After the installation process is completed, it took alot of time during lunch. I tried to purge and reinstall but the problem but it was not fixed.
I am currently using `Zend Server 8.5.7,Enterprise Trial Edition, Development profile`.

It throws out this error:

> Zend Server failed during initialization: An exception was raised
>   while creating "Configuration\License\ZemUtilsWrapper"; no instance
>   returned An exception was raised while creating
>   "Configuration\License\ZemUtilsWrapper"; no instance returned Error
>   executing the query. Probably DB is locked

Comment: Problem Solved: The compatible distro for Zend Server 8.5 is Ubuntu 14.04 not 16.04. So, there might be some compatible issue. I downgraded my ubuntu by reinstalling the stable LTS version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, ZSD did not collect the license details and the UI could not retrieve it.
A possible fix would be to remove (move aside, delete, your choice) data/db/zsd.db and then immediately restart the Zend Server Daemon in the Services window.

This will force ZSD to rescan your ini files and retrieve the license.

Source: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=111068&start=10